# Does Apache Alias support relative paths?

Tags: path, apache-http-server, alias

I'm trying to alias a file using a relative path from the document root, like this:

```
Alias /js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js lib/jquery-1.9.1/jquery-1.9.1.min.js
```

It does not work, but I can't find anything in [the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) about relative paths.

Does it support relative paths?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a *relative* directory-path (or file-path) as the target of the `Alias` directive. However, it is relative to the [`ServerRoot`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serverroot), not the `DocumentRoot`.

One of the main uses of the `Alias` directive is to be able to access files outside of the current `DocumentRoot`, so it wouldn't necessarily be logical to have this resolve relative to the `DocumentRoot`.

If you wanted to "alias" file(s) relative to the `DocumentRoot`, then you can use mod_rewrite. For example, in a *server* or *virtualhost* context:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/js/((jquery-1\.9\.1)\.min\.js)$ /lib/$1/$2 [L]
```

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serverroot